# minor issue in jQuery if statement and .remove()

Tags: jquery, html

Below is my jQuery for a project i am working on, i have also included a jsFiddle link.

Basically, everything works beautifully until my if statement. So far i have it set up that if someone chooses a friday or a saturday date, it removes certain times from the select box, this is fine. However if someone then decides to change the day from a friday or saturday the removed options wont be added back in, i know why, but what is the best way to put them back in? I could do an else statement but i think it'd just duplicate the removed options

code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedDay = "#selected_day";
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "DD, d M yy",
            altField: selectedDay,
            altFormat: "DD",
            onSelect:function(){
                $(selectedDay).change()
            }
        });
        $(selectedDay).change(function () {
            if($(selectedDay).val() == 'Friday' || $(selectedDay).val() == 'Saturday'){
                $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/c3u5B/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instead of removing, you could `hide()`, like:

```
$(selectedDay).change(function () {
   var day = $(this).val();
   if($(selectedDay).val() == 'Friday' || $(selectedDay).val() == 'Saturday'){
        $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').hide();
   }
   else {
        $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').show();
   }
});
```

Updated [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3u5B/19/)

Comment: Of course! Kicking myself as it's such a simple thing! haha. Thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also disable them using `.prop()`. This is maybe slighty more user friendly than hiding them as the user sees, that some values are disabled and not missing:

```
var value = false;
if ($(selectedDay).val() == 'Friday' || $(selectedDay).val() == 'Saturday') {
    value = true;
}

$('#times')
    .find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]')
    .prop('disabled', value);
```

**DEMO**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/R4K9Y/)

Comment: Personally i agree, however knowing this client, their customers may get confused as to why they can't click on it and not think it through that it's not available. So in this instance i need to remove them, but +1 for the idea

Comment: @AndyHolmes Thanks for your feedback. I'm glad I could throw in my 2 cents as well. :)

Comment: Most definitely going to use this idea in the future though. Very good :)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than removing them from the DOM, just use `hide()` and `show()`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedDay = "#selected_day";
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "DD, d M yy",
            altField: selectedDay,
            altFormat: "DD",
            onSelect:function(){
                $(selectedDay).change()
            }
        });
        $(selectedDay).change(function () {
            var day = $(this).val();
            if($(selectedDay).val() == 'Friday' || $(selectedDay).val() == 'Saturday') {
                $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').hide();
            }
            else
            {
                $('#times option:not(:visible)').show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here's an [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c3u5B/21/)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine...
http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/c3u5B/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var times = $('#times').clone();
      alert(times.html());
    var selectedDay = "#selected_day";
    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "DD, d M yy",
            altField: selectedDay,
            altFormat: "DD",
            onSelect:function(){
                $(selectedDay).change()
            }
        });
        $(selectedDay).change(function () {
            var day = $(this).val();

            if($(selectedDay).val() == 'Friday' || $(selectedDay).val() == 'Saturday'){
                $('#times').find('option[value="6pm"], option[value="8pm"], option[value="10pm"], option[value="11pm"]').remove();
            }
            else{
            $("#times").html(times.html());
            }
        });
    });
});
```